# Correct way to make an NSView the firstresponder to all Undo/Redo actions irrespective of active/focused view/control

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdocument, nsundomanager, document-based

I have a standard document based application whose main window has two NSViews.

1. Is it possible to make NSView1 the firstresponder for Undo/Redo actions even when NSView2 is the focused view.
2. Is it possible to have the context for Edit menuitem permanently set to NSView1's context. E.g. if an NSTextField in NSView2 has focus and the Edit menu item is opened, by default it opens in the context of NSTexfield's current state, can this be overriden?

If either is possible, how does one go about achieving this?

C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the solution, there's a rather convenient method in NSResponder called [validateProposedFirstResponder](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/validateProposedFirstResponder:forEvent:). With a little manoeuvring, one should be able to achieve the desired effect.